# How to read firestore data in Realtime using Next JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm using next js 13 with firebase v9. so in order to read from firestore i used a react-firebase-hook package. but when i try to use it it throws the error `FirebaseError: Expected type 'pa', but it was: a custom $n object`.

```
const constraints = [];
  if (price) constraints.push(orderBy("price", price == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

  const livings = collection(db, "livingPosts");

  const [living, loading, error] = useCollection(
    query(collection(db, "livingPosts"), ...constraints)
  );
```

before this i used the usual way by creating an async method and call it inside use effect. but this will only run on the app start, so that means in order to get new data or filter the returned data the user will have to refresh the page. and that's not ideal.

```
const getData = async () => {
    const constraints = [];

    if (price)
      constraints.push(orderBy("price", price == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

    const livings = collection(db, "livingPosts");
    let q = query(livings, ...constraints);

    const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const dataQ = qSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    console.log(dataQ);
    setDatas(dataQ);

    // console.log("first datas");
    // console.log(datas);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

what i wanted to do with both ways is i have compound queries that run with conditions.

```
if (price) constraints.push(orderBy("price", price == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));
if (type) constraints.push(where("type", "==", type);
```

so how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i made it work. i'll post an answer b/c it might help someone someday.

the trick to fetch firestore datas in realtime is to not call the `getData()` inside of `useEffect()`. that's b/c `useEffect()` will run it once when the page loads. there might be a way to listen to the changes and apply to `useEffect()` hook as an argument, but this way is easy.

so what i did is after creating the `getData()` just call it .

```
const getData = async () => {
  ...rest of the function
};

getData();
```

this did the best job. Hope this Helps.